# AWS R53 not resolving name

Tags: heroku, dns, amazon-route53

I'm developing a web site and I'm having problems with AWS Rout 53

Initially I was using digital ocean, so I set up the A records to the IP of the server and updated my registrar nameservers (godaddy).
Everything was working fine.

Now I'm hosting on heroku, but it's not resolving the name.

If I visit `teamcomp.net`, I correctly get redirected to `www.teamcomp.net`, so I'd think the S3 bucket is configured correctly.

But after that, Firefox can't find the server at `www.teamcomp.net`.

```
Server not found

Check the address for typing errors such as ww.example.com instead of www.example.com
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

I followed the instruction at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53 , I added the domains to the heroku app and the nameserver of the registrar are correctly set.

```
$ heroku domains
=== mysterious-reef-3637 Heroku Domain
mysterious-reef-3637.herokuapp.com

=== mysterious-reef-3637 Custom Domains
Domain Name       DNS Target                        
────────────────  ──────────────────────────────────
www.teamcomp.net  mysterious-reef-3637.herokuapp.com
teamcomp.net      mysterious-reef-3637.herokuapp.com
```

This is the configuration I currently have. It looks to me like I'm doing everything like the guide said, but I can not reach the website from that domain (it works if I use heroku domain)

[image: r53 configuration]

```
$ host teamcomp.net
Host teamcomp.net not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

What can I do to fix it?

Additional infos

```
$ dig +recurse +trace teamcomp.net any

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.5-Ubuntu <<>> +recurse +trace teamcomp.net any
;; global options: +cmd
.           304830  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           304830  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           304830  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           304830  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           304830  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           304830  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           304830  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           304830  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           304830  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           304830  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           304830  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           304830  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           304830  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
;; Received 755 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1) in 3393 ms

net.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
net.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
net.            86400   IN  DS  35886 8 2 7862B27F5F516EBE19680444D4CE5E762981931842C465F00236401D 8BD973EE
net.            86400   IN  RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20151224170000 20151214160000 62530 . Kmd1EaxlpKS2T8PZIV/HWmZe8glRgOKjgtjfuvx4D4YDPGRnyOxWXVql 4Y8srSFmvDPDR382hMQWLaOwjnVCO4dMWPnRIoYvzqo05a2/7EOJDXlV 6WczFZKy+9M7oUj4XeeHrpi04ypUj/gXvnCMNKk3/5QJl4T8MovWEHeu hXw=
;; Received 733 bytes from 192.228.79.201#53(b.root-servers.net) in 7182 ms

teamcomp.net.       172800  IN  NS  ns-1351.awsdns-40.org.
teamcomp.net.       172800  IN  NS  ns-2043.awsdns-63.co.uk.
teamcomp.net.       172800  IN  NS  ns-210.awsdns-26.com.
teamcomp.net.       172800  IN  NS  ns-526.awsdns-01.net.
A1RT98BS5QGC9NFI51S9HCI47ULJG6JH.net. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - A1RUUFFJKCT2Q54P78F8EJGJ8JBK7I8B NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
A1RT98BS5QGC9NFI51S9HCI47ULJG6JH.net. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20151218061702 20151211050702 37703 net. QEvwTsJgNbCEgO6sLxxz09CG5Ugs4hPXoRo+8W5o4Xn5nrkdN7lw0rNI DFS/C6dJtShsOkX2/0EIpp8DaGAvjgTs6jLu+oZzgTaedKHSk0cQUPVf EcGNbbpp8FCHz0yUMBes9FPg8WAe+DXNZ++lCjtK5aO89EEWJqNEOjfP vmA=
UC4NBKDSCVJ8ARDU0BVH1BBDDQ15GR8I.net. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - UC518K8QR415HBJULMN8MLAPPT20CKR1 NS DS RRSIG
UC4NBKDSCVJ8ARDU0BVH1BBDDQ15GR8I.net. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20151220062946 20151213051946 37703 net. Re7MIW4RzyQdlEfoIM1TrQIq8mG5VvLlGvDfba+NeUAbnKNZMmW+WCYr n3Jktc9xVXJoecBZg+CSTG03CWqG8GkA8RiQQjAVKF1dcWRph6mGLglM crgzBFvK4H+uo6WJDkOowm7jA736J/9/FWJ1GoBXMoFMvz/HmPiujpRR Hgs=
;; Received 695 bytes from 192.43.172.30#53(i.gtld-servers.net) in 548 ms

teamcomp.net.       5   IN  A   54.231.131.76
teamcomp.net.       172800  IN  NS  ns-1351.awsdns-40.org.
teamcomp.net.       172800  IN  NS  ns-2043.awsdns-63.co.uk.
teamcomp.net.       172800  IN  NS  ns-210.awsdns-26.com.
teamcomp.net.       172800  IN  NS  ns-526.awsdns-01.net.
teamcomp.net.       900 IN  SOA ns-210.awsdns-26.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
;; Received 255 bytes from 205.251.194.14#53(ns-526.awsdns-01.net) in 494 ms
```

Comment: Right now both teamcomp.net and www.teamcomp.net resolve just fine so it could be a Route 53 propagation delay. Was there anything you changed to make it work?

Comment: Nope, still same configuration.
I noticed that from my phone it's working, but my PC is not.
My PC is behind the university network, I guess it's DNS is taking a long time to update the field. My phone can't access the site as well when I connect with the university WiFi.
Is there a way to be sure about that?

Comment: It could be your provider incorrect DNS cache. The TTL on the screenshot seems to be right.  These addresses resolve fine from all over the world: http://whoer.net/checkwhois?host=teamcomp.net, https://pulse.turbobytes.com/results/56704afbecbe402ea700094c/, https://dnschecker.org/#A/teamcomp.net, https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/teamcomp.net

Comment: You can try switching to public Google DNS resolver: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like incorrectly set university DNS resolver. Switching to any other public DNS resolver should solve the problem: http://www.circleid.com/posts/20110407_top_public_dns_resolvers_compared/.

Here are some tutorials for how to change one's DNS server on Windows 10 and OS X:

- http://solverbase.com/w/Windows_10:_Changing_DNS_Servers
- http://www.plus.net/support/software/dns/changing_dns_mac.shtml
- http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/02/change-dns-command-line-mac-os-x/
- https://use.opendns.com/
- https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using?hl=en

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately you are forced to use the DNS provided by the university, otherwise you don't have access to the Internet (I usually use Google's one, but every time I connect to the university network I need to switch to the default or I can't connect to the net)

Comment: If you add how to switch for the main OSes (even a link is fine) I'll accept your answer, so that if some user has my problem and can change the DNS, can find out how to do that

Comment: Sure, added some links. I believe your university DNS resolver cache will eventually expire.

Comment: Yeah, it expired eventually! Thanks :)